# How can a rope push an object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> If a 1 kg object is attached to a massless rope which moves in a uniform circular motion in a vertical circle such that it has a period of 8 seconds and a radius of 1 meter. Find the tension at the top of the circle. Is the rope compressed or stretched?

My solution: $$F_c=mg+T=\frac{m4\pi^2r}{t^2}$$
$$T=\frac{m4\pi^2r}{t^2}-mg=-9.1$$

Which shows that the tension is acting against gravity, hence pointing away from the center of the circle. Shouldn't tension always pull the object towards the center of the circle at all times? Also according to the answer of the textbook the rope is being compressed. How can the rope be compressed?

Comment: In physics, strings and ropes and chains are usually assumed to buckle in compression. The person who set the question seems to be assuming the rope is rigid like a rod. This is something which you need to ask the person who devised the question.

Comment: Please read carefully [our guidelines for homework and exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) as well as for [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/). We are not a homework-help service, but we can help with the *conceptual* aspects of this question if it is rephrased to make those clear.

Answer (score 1):

The object, according to the OP, is moving in ***uniform*** circular motion in a vertical circle.

The uniform part means that the velocity of the object is fixed;  it travels $2\pi$ metres in $8$ seconds, so the fixed velocity is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ m/s.

The centripetal force needed to keep a $1$ kg object moving in a $1$ metre radius circle, $F_C$ is given by $$F_C= \frac{mv^2}{r}=\frac{1\times \pi^2}{16}$$

The force of gravity, acting downward on the object, $mg$, has the tension T, also acting downward at the top of the circle. So, **at that moment** $$F_C = T+mg$$ $$T=F_C-mg=\frac{1\times \pi^2}{16}-9.8=-9.2 \text{ Newtons}$$

So, indeed, the "rope" is under compression at the top of the circle.

In addition, the "rope" must also resist bending, since it must exert a tangential force on the mass to lift it up one side and lower it down the other, all at constant velocity. The solution of @Mozibur Ullah, a frozen rope, is a good one.